# Error 1070 Pig Could not resolve PigSorage using imports:

Tags: apache-pig, hue

I'm trying to read a file with pig and I have the error indicated in the title.

data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/pigexample/commands' USING PigSorage('\n') as
(command:chararray);

DUMPdata;
The file contains the following:

```
**SOF**
whoami
pwd
ls
say
saw
source
<1>
source
<1>
exit
**EOF**
**SOF**
where's
<1>
```

I don't understand why I get the error supposedly its delimiter is the line break, I'm also trying with another file whose delimiter is the tab ('\t') and it doesn't work either. Does anyone know what the delimiter is? PS: I don't know what tag to put on the question.

As explained above, I expected it to open the file with the indicated delimiter but it does not work.
I have already tried with \t \n

Answer (score 1):

I have already seen my mistake

```
data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/pigexample/commands' USING PigSorage('\n') as (command:chararray);

data = LOAD '/user/cloudera/pigexample/commands' USING PigStorage('\n') as (command:chararray);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).